# change the uiview frame when it has some constraints

Tags: ios, uiview, constraints

There is a subview (UIView) on the main view, I want change the size of the subview (_test).

`_test` has two constraints:

1. top space to main view: 20
2. trailling space to main view: 136

When I want change the size of _test (subview),but this seems not work:

```
self._test.frame = CGRectMake(self._test.frame.origin.x + 10, 
                              self._test.frame.origin.y, 
                              self._test.frame.size.width - 10, 
                              self._test.frame.size.height);
```

I think this is because constraints, but, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `_test` has two constraints:
>
> top space to main view: 20
>
> trailling space to main view: 136

Well, there's your first problem. If this really is a generic UIView, then that is not enough constraints. If you are going to use constraints at all, you must *completely determine* both the position and the size of the view, and you are failing to do that. Thus, your constraints are invalid.

Once your constraints become valid, then indeed you will face the fact that you cannot set the position and size of the view by means of its `frame`. Setting the `frame` and using constraints are mutually exclusive! If you are going to position and size this thing using constraints, then to reposition or resize it you must change its *constraints*, not its `frame`.